# Chaining multiple ActiveRecord `or` queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I've got an array of columns that I want to loop through and optionally chain an `or` query onto an ActiveRecord query chain. I can get it to work, but the resulting query appends the `or` onto the query chain, therefore making the columns in my inital query optional. Here's my class:

```rb
class Claim
  class MatchingAttributeFinder
    ATTRIBUTE_GROUPS_TO_MATCH = [
      ["teacher_reference_number"],
      ["email_address"],
      ["national_insurance_number"],
      ["bank_account_number", "bank_sort_code", "building_society_roll_number"],
    ].freeze

    def initialize(source_claim, claims_to_compare = Claim.submitted)
      @source_claim = source_claim
      @claims_to_compare = claims_to_compare
    end

    def matching_claims
      claims = @claims_to_compare.where.not(id: @source_claim.id)

      ATTRIBUTE_GROUPS_TO_MATCH.each do |attributes|
        vals = values_for_attributes(attributes)

        next if vals.blank?

        concatenated_columns = "CONCAT(#{attributes.join(",")})"

        claims = claims.or(
          Claim.where("LOWER(#{concatenated_columns}) = LOWER(?)", vals.join)
        )
      end

      claims
    end

    private

    def values_for_attributes(attributes)
      attributes.map { |attribute|
        @source_claim.read_attribute(attribute)
      }.reject(&:blank?)
    end
  end
end
```

The generated SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT "claims".* FROM "claims" WHERE (((("claims"."submitted_at" IS NOT NULL AND "claims"."id" != 'a7b25b99-4477-42b1-96ab-8262582c5541' OR (LOWER(CONCAT(teacher_reference_number)) = LOWER('0902344'))) OR (LOWER(CONCAT(email_address)) = LOWER('genghis.khan@mongol-empire.com'))) OR (LOWER(CONCAT(national_insurance_number)) = LOWER('QQ891011C'))) OR (LOWER(CONCAT(bank_account_number,bank_sort_code,building_society_roll_number)) = LOWER('34682151972654123456789/ABCD')))
```

But what I actually want is more like this:

```
SELECT "claims".* FROM "claims" WHERE "claims"."submitted_at" IS NOT NULL AND "claims"."id" != 'd6a53b4d-c569-49e6-a2ea-ac44b69b0451' AND (LOWER(concat(teacher_reference_number)) = LOWER('0902344') OR LOWER(concat(email_address)) = LOWER('genghis.khan@mongol-empire.com') OR LOWER(concat(national_insurance_number)) = LOWER('QQ891011C') OR LOWER(concat(bank_account_number,bank_sort_code,building_society_roll_number)) = LOWER('34682151972654123456789/ABCD'))
```

Is there any way to set up something like an empty scope that I can chain my `OR` queries to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try chaning all the "or" together first and then chain the original query

```
def matching_claims
  claims = @claims_to_compare.where.not(id: @source_claim.id)

  ors = nil

  ATTRIBUTE_GROUPS_TO_MATCH.each do |attributes|
    vals = values_for_attributes(attributes)

    next if vals.blank?

    concatenated_columns = "CONCAT(#{attributes.join(",")})"

    aux = Claim.where("LOWER(#{concatenated_columns}) = LOWER(?)", vals.join)
    if ors.nil?
      ors = aux
    else
      ors = ors.or(aux)
    end
  end

  claims.merge(ors)
end
```

Comment: Ah, I tried an approach like this. The only issue is `to_sql` generates the full SQL query (including the `SELECT *..` part), so I get the error `ERROR:  subquery must return only one column`